# Why two type result for my python script?

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, mechanize

i have script like this

```
 import mechanize
 url = "http://www.globalhide.com/browse.php?u=u=http://www.whoisxmlapi.com/whoisserver/WhoisService?domainName=google.com"
 br = mechanize.Browser()
 br.set_handle_robots(False)
 br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.1) Gecko/2008071615 Fedora/3.0.1-1.fc9 Firefox/3.0.1')]
 response = br.open(url)
 content = response.read()
 f = open('q.html', 'w')
 f.write(content)
 f.close()
```

i need the result like [this](http://www.globalhide.com/browse.php?u=http://www.whoisxmlapi.com/whoisserver/WhoisService?domainName=google.com)
 when i run this from python shell ,the result correct. but when i save this in a something.py file and run like this `python something.py` the content of q.html [image]
What wrong with my code?

Comment: You are trying to do something that globalhide doesn't want you to do. Can I suggest that you stop doing it? ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's anything wrong with your code as such. Changing the requested url results in good data returned.

The block is being implemented by globalhide.com themselves. The link you added in your question gives the same page as you've attached (more or less). I can't tell you exactly how this hotlink blocking is implemented, but it could be through the referrer heading. Looking into [referrer spoofing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referer_spoofing) may help you here.

**Edit**

Jumped the gun a little bit there wrt referrer spoofing. I'd go with Aaron's cookie suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

For that URL, I sometimes get the XML, and sometimes get the "no hotlinking" page in Chrome Linux. The first hit returns the no-hotlinking page for the same url. If I clear my cookies and visit that page again, I get the no-hotlinking image.

It appears that a Cookie is required for this site. The following should work with your code.

```
policy = mechanize.DefaultCookiePolicy(rfc2965=True) 
cj = mechanize.LWPCookieJar(policy=policy)
br.set_cookiejar(cj)
```

For more information on the different methods to implement cookies, check out [Mechanize Docs - Cookies](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/doc.html#supplying-a-cookiejar).

**Edit 1** You should save the cookie jar, see [Cookielib - Save](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cookielib.html#cookielib.FileCookieJar.save).

**Edit 2** here's the cookie information that site set for me:

```
Name:   __utma
Content:    53296278.1653562620.1363413018.1311413018.1337443014.1
Domain: .globalhide.com
Path:   /
Send for:   Any kind of connection
Accessible to script:   Yes
Created:    Wednesday, May 1, 2013 6:56:58 AM
Expires:    Friday, May 1, 2015 6:56:58 AM
Name:   s
Content:    x2tjlhb1qfidn5t1ds8kvd24p5
Domain: www.globalhide.com
Path:   /
Send for:   Any kind of connection
Accessible to script:   Yes
Created:    Wednesday, May 1, 2013 6:56:57 AM
Expires:    When the browsing session ends
```

Comment: Are you saving the cookie? I do not have experience with Mechanize personally, but this save-cookie method worked for me: [How To Save Mechanize Browser Cookies To File](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7510806/how-to-save-mechanize-browser-cookies-to-file)