# Python transfer mechanize browser session

Tags: python, web-scraping, mechanize-python

I'm having a little difficulty trying to navigate a website past the login screen. I've done this using [mechanize](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mechanize/). However once I navigate past the login page I want to interact with the page, click attributes, etc. which mechanize cannot do. I also want to do this all "behind the curtain" so the browser window is invisible (trying not to use selenium).

Here is the code I use to login. What can I do past this to start interacting with the page

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
#get computer browser

br.set_handle_robots(False)
#what robots?

br.open("www.website.com")
#open website

br.select_form(nr=0)
#get the main form    

br.set_all_readonly(False)

for control in br.form.controls:
    print control

user_control = br.form.controls[0]
user_control._value = 'username'

user_password = br.form.controls[1]
user_password._value = 'password'

br.submit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to "transfer" cookies from `mechanize` to `selenium` and use `selenium` with a *headless browser* like [`PhantomJS`](http://phantomjs.org/) or with a [virtual display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6183276/how-do-i-run-selenium-in-xvfb). Or, just switch to `selenium`+`PhantomJS` completely (including the authentication step).

See also:

- [Python: how to dump cookies of a mechanize.Browser instance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/606072/python-how-to-dump-cookies-of-a-mechanize-browser-instance)
- [How to save and load cookies using python selenium webdriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15058462/how-to-save-and-load-cookies-using-python-selenium-webdriver)

Comment: Yes this is perfect. I switched to phantomjs and it was everything I could hope it could be and more. Ended up rewriting everything to selenium. Thanks a bunch!